# How can I prevent my widget from re-updating every time the device's orientation is changed?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I have an Android widget that makes quite a bit of network requests in it's `onUpdate` method. My widget is expected to refresh once a day. It always does very heavy `Canvas` drawing using an `AsyncTask`.

When I turn my device from the portrait orientation to the landscape orientation and back to the portrait orientation, it seems that the `onUpdate` method is invoked again and all those heavy network requests are issued again.

Can I prevent my application from re-updating when the orientation is changed if it is possible?

Comment: cache the data and the last update time. Only update if a certain amount of time has passed otherwise use the cached data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My widget is expected to refresh once a day

You do not have complete control over that. The home screen is welcome to trigger `onUpdate()` calls more frequently, for whatever reason.

> Can I prevent my application from re-updating when the orientation is changed if it is possible?

No, but as Kuffs suggests, you can cut down on the expense of the update process:

- Cache the results of the network I/O to disk
- Cache the bitmap (which is what I presume the "very heavy Canvas drawing" results in) to disk

Or, just ignore the `onUpdate()` call entirely, if it is too soon and you feel confident that the home screen has not somehow lost your prior `RemoteViews`. Personally, I would regenerate the `RemoteViews` using cached content, just in case some home screen implementation discarded your prior `RemoteViews` (e.g., process was terminated and restarted).

Also, please use an `IntentService`, not an `AsyncTask`, for processing long `onUpdate()` work. There is nothing keeping your process in memory once `onUpdate()` returns otherwise, and your process may be terminated before your work completes.